# AWS S3 peer not authenticated

Tags: java, ssl, amazon-s3, certificate, amazon-web-services

I am using the `AWS Java SDK` in an application that uploads small files about once a minute to `S3`. The application has been running uninterrupted for two weeks, but had two major periods in which uploads throw an `SSL-related` `peer not authenticated` error.

The first period lasted about three days. It wasn't abrupt; but "sputtered out" as more and more uploads threw exceptions until it was doing none within a few minutes.

The second period began about a week ago and has not ended.

On the `AWS` forum, an Amazon employee seems to [recommend solving this problem](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=283360&#283360) by not validating Amazon's certificate.

Please explain if I've misunderstood this, or what else I should try.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue but with my EC2 instance a while back. I was using GnuTLS libraries and SSL communication. Like it is mentioned on that thread, you need to code and allow for acceptance of self-signed certificates or if the servers identity does not matter to you ( as in if you dont have issues with not validating the server..) you can disable checking the server authenticity. It worked fine for me thereafter. It happens once in a while like you said and I am still unsure as to why there is this behavior.

Comment: Interesting to hear your experience. This is a commercial product transferring what may be sensitive data, so going to an all-trusting http client isn't an option for me.

Comment: in that case you can go for a self signed cert acceptance. That should be much safer and solve ure issue. If not, I simply suggest reattempting the connection after a few seconds of delay in your code if the problem arises. Sometimes there is a load based issue.

Comment: you could also take a look at this if you havent: http://theskeleton.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/avoiding-the-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated-with-httpclient/